# SSL Certificate on migration to AWS

Tags: ssl, amazon-web-services, migration, certificate, godaddy

I migrated a Windows Server 2012 R2 running in vmware to AWS.

Is it necessary to make any changes to the GoDaddy SSL certificate or I can keep it as is?

Answer (score 3):

SSL Certificate works with Web-server. You can use one SSL Certificate on any Web-server it not depends on OS or Virtual environment. So you can keep it as is.

Comment: I kept it and it didn't work. 
Godaddy's support told me that I have to create a new certificate.

Comment: Where you use your SSL Certificate?